# Odd random.randint behavior

Tags: python, random

I wrote a program to create the appearance of a snake sliding down the screen.  You can pass in a width and length for the path the snake travels down.  The snake moves at random staying within the width confines given.

All works fairly well, except when testing my guard rails to keep the snake within the defined width. I noticed at times the snake position (`left_side`) appears to be able to go to a negative value.  Given that I have a guard rail that when `left_side` == 0 it should only be able to move back right given that when that condition is true my only values I can add to is should be 0 or 1.

How do I fix this?

My code:

```
import random
import time

def path(path_width, snake_pos):
    path = ""
    for space in range(path_width + 1):
        if space == 0:
            path = path + "|"
        if space == snake_pos:
            path = path + "()"
        if space == width: 
            path = path + "|"
        else:
            path = path + " "
    return path

width = int(input("How wide is your course? "))
length = int(input("How long is your course? "))

left_side = random.randint(1, width -1)

i=1
while i < length:
    if left_side == 0:
        left_side = left_side + random.randint(0, 1)
    if left_side == width:
        left_side = left_side + random.randint(-1, 0)
    else:
        left_side = left_side + random.randint(-1, 1)
    print(path(width, left_side) + " : leftside = " + str(left_side))
    i += 1
    time.sleep(.05)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your guard rail lies here:

```
if left_side == 0:
    left_side = left_side + random.randint(0, 1)
if left_side == width:
    left_side = left_side + random.randint(-1, 0)
else:
    left_side = left_side + random.randint(-1, 1)
```

The problem is that you're using an `if`/`if`/`else` workflow; if the first `if` condition is met, it will execute the code within, and then check the second `if` statement and execute either that code, or the code in the attached `else` block.

Here's the current workflow of your code: it checks if `left_side` is 0, and if so adds either 0 or 1 to `left_side`. It then checks if `left_side` is equal to `width`. If it is, then either -1 or 0 will be added to `left_side`. If it isn't, then the `else` statement will be executed and either -1, 0, or 1 will be added to `left_side`.

This means that every iteration of the loop, `left_side` has a chance of being decreased by one, because either the second `if` block or the `else` block below it will execute every iteration, and the `random.randint` statement in both has the chance to evaluate to -1.

The solution is simply to change the second `if` statement to an `elif` statement, like so:

```
if left_side == 0:
    left_side = left_side + random.randint(0, 1)
elif left_side == width:
    left_side = left_side + random.randint(-1, 0)
else:
    left_side = left_side + random.randint(-1, 1)
```

Now, if the first condition (`left_side == 0`) is met, it will not check if `left_side == width` in the same iteration of the loop, meaning `left_side` will not be decreased in that iteration.

Comment: That makes perfect sense and makes me feel silly for asking.  Thanks Pika!! Really appreciate the guidance!!

Comment: Still thinking about this one and I am confused again.  I dont think that second if condition should have been met unless I also set width to zero correct?  I saw this behavior when width was set to a positive integer.

Comment: @Brewcious see my edit, when you set `width` higher than 0 the `else` statement executes most iterations, which can also decrease `left_side`.

Comment: Got it now.  Makes sense.  Complete Python novice here so really do appreciate the explanation.  Thanks again Pika.